# How to detect multiple press on volume buttons on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to start my activity at fifth press on volume buttons. I can do it via single press, but it is not comfortable to use.

```
public class VolumeButtonClickListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int i = 0;      

        if(intent.getAction()
             .equals("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION")) 
         {
                i++;
                if(i>=0){
                     i=0;
                     //go to my activity
                }
         }
   }
}
```

This does not work because of "i" variable is being declared every time volume button is pressed. How can I fix that?

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` to save count number.

Comment: If you use preferences or static int var, then you probably also want to check time or use delayed handler msg after 30 seconds or whatever as you would then get 1-4 presses say 1 hour later or with pref you could get 1-4 days, weeks, months, etc later. With pref that means you would have to save the time of last use to pref as well. I think static var with handler is better if it will stick around here. But whatever works for you.